# ASP.NET Core 6 : custom vallidation attribute with client-side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0, unobtrusive-validation

I have forms that I have had to create custom validation attributes for. My custom attribute works at the server, but I do not want it to go to the server to validate this. I would love for it to work at the client-side.

What this validator does is looks to see what has been selected for a stated property. If the value of the property is selected, then this property is required.

The attribute is applied like this:

```
[AnotherTest("CurrentlyPracticing", 1,
 ErrorMessage = "Required if practicing.")]
public string? ProfLicense { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

As you can see, the `ProfLicense` property is only required if `CurrentlyPracticing = 1`.

Here is my model class, custom validation attribute code, and view for this project.

My model class (*ignore the commented out portions - it is a work in progress*):

```
public class ApplicationVM
{
    // other attributes removed because of Stackoverflow space requirements
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must answer this question.")]
    [Display(Name = "Are you a licensed medical practitioner?")]
    public int? LicMedPract { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfTrue(nameof(LicMedPract), ErrorMessage = "An answer is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Currently Practicing?")]
    public int? CurrentlyPracticing { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfTrue(nameof(CurrentlyPracticing), ErrorMessage = "You must select a Specialty.")]
    [Display(Name = "Practice Specialty:")]
    public int? SpecialtyID { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfTrue(nameof(SpecialtyID), ErrorMessage = "You must type an Other Specialty.")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Display(Name = "Other Specialty:")]
    public string PracSpecOther { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Display(Name = "License Number")]
    [AnotherTest("CurrentlyPracticing", 1,
     ErrorMessage = "Required if practicing.")]
    public string? ProfLicense { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [MaxLength(2)]
    [Display(Name = "State Licensed")]
    [AnotherTest("CurrentlyPracticing", 1,
     ErrorMessage = "Required if practicing.")]
    public string? ProfLicenseState { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Here is my custom validation attribute:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace pportal2.common.Validation
{
    public class AnotherTestAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {
        private readonly string _propertyName;
        private readonly object _desiredValue;
        private readonly RequiredAttribute _required;

        public AnotherTestAttribute(string propertyName, Object desiredValue)
        {
            _propertyName = propertyName;
            _desiredValue = desiredValue;
            _required = new RequiredAttribute();
        }

        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-testif", errorMessage);

            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-testif-propertyname", _propertyName);
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-testif-desiredvalue", _desiredValue.ToString());
        }

        protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var dependentValue = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(_propertyName).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (dependentValue.ToString() == _desiredValue.ToString())
            {
                if (!_required.IsValid(value))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        private static bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
        {
            if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return false;
            }

            attributes.Add(key, value);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My view (here I think my issue is at the validator section. This is at the bottom of the scripts):

```
<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
<h1 class="text-center">PACE Program Initial Application</h1>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
<form asp-action="Application" id="application">
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>
                <label>Professional Information:</label>
            </h4>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label asp-for="LicMedPract" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="LicMedPract" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.YesNo2"></select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="LicMedPract" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divHiddenPracticeInfo" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                            <label asp-for="CurrentlyPracticing" class="control-label"></label>
                            <select asp-for="CurrentlyPracticing" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.YesNo2"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="CurrentlyPracticing" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3" id="divPracticeSpecialty" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label asp-for="SpecialtyID" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="SpecialtyID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Specialty"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="SpecialtyID" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3" id="divPracSpecOther" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label asp-for="PracSpecOther" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="PracSpecOther" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="PracSpecOther" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5 class="col-md-12">Please include all letters and numbers.</h5>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                            <label asp-for="ProfLicense" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ProfLicense" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ProfLicense" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group  col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                            <label asp-for="ProfLicenseState" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="ProfLicenseState" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ProfLicenseState" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                            <label asp-for="DEA" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="DEA" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="DEA" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger">
            <span id="message2"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   // Other script code removed because of space limitations on stackoverflow....

    $.validator.addMethod("testif", function (value, element, parameters) {
        var practicing = $(parameters[0]).val(), desiredvalue = parameters[1], proflicense = value;
        console.log(practicing[0].val());

        if (practicing && practicing[0] === 1) {
            alert(value);
            return value != null;
        }
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("testif", "desiredvalue", function (options) {
        options.rules.testif = {};
        options.
        options.messages["testif"] = options.message;
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: You never stated what the issue is.  "Not works" is not enough.  Describe what it's doing and what you expect it to do.  Also state what troubleshooting you've performed and if there are any JavaScript console errors.  Read and follow the "Asking" section:  https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: How do I describe it.  I do not know how to do the JavaScript side.  Currently, the JavaScript side always comes back that the field is NOT VALID.  I know the code is not correct.  I need help with that.  It needs to verify that the listed field in the attribute is the listed selection.  If so, it needs to verify that the field is not null.

Comment: Could you focus the problem to one property?

Comment: I can.  It is the Attribute/Validator, AnotherTest for the property ProfLIcense or ProfLicenseState.  Both of these need to be required if CurrentlyPracticing has a value of 1 (Yes).  As I have stated, the attribute/validation works perfectly at Server Side.  I am having issues writing the Client-Side.  I cannot get it to do what I need.  I need the JavaScript validator to function the same.

Comment: I tried to narrow the view to just the section the jquery/javascript validator will apply to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small working sample you can try reference
ApplicationVM.cs

```
    public class ApplicationVM
    {

        [Display(Name = "Currently Practicing?")]
        public int? CurrentlyPracticing { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "State Licensed")]
        [AnotherTest("CurrentlyPracticing", 1,ErrorMessage = "Required if practicing.")]
        public string? ProfLicense { get; set; }
    }
```

AnotherTestAttribute.cs

```
    public class AnotherTestAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {
        private readonly string _propertyName;
        private readonly object _desiredValue;

        public AnotherTestAttribute(string propertyName, object desiredValue)
        {
            _propertyName = propertyName;
            _desiredValue = desiredValue;

        }
        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-anothertest", errorMessage);

            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-anothertest-propertyname", _propertyName);
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-anothertest-desiredvalue", _desiredValue.ToString());
        }

        private static bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
        {
            if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return false;
            }
            attributes.Add(key, value);

            return true;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //I didn't implement server validation
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        }
    }
```

Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new ApplicationVM());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(ApplicationVM applicationVM)
        {
            return View(applicationVM);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model ApplicationVM
@{
    List<SelectListItem> choices1 = new()
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1",Text="Yes"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "0",Text="No"},
            };


    ViewBag.YesNo2 = choices1;
}

<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
    <h1 class="text-center">PACE Program Initial Application</h1>
</div>

<div class ="col-md-8 m-auto">@Model.ProfLicense</div>

<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
    <form asp-action="index" method="post">

        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <label asp-for="CurrentlyPracticing" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="CurrentlyPracticing" class="form-control" id="CurrentlyPracticing" asp-items="ViewBag.YesNo2"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CurrentlyPracticing" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <label asp-for="ProfLicense" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ProfLicense" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ProfLicense" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
</div>



@section scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.validator.addMethod("anothertest",
            function (value, element, parameters) {
                var propertyname = $(element).data('val-anothertest-propertyname');
                var desiredvalue = $(element).data('val-anothertest-desiredvalue');

                if ((value.trim() == "") && (document.getElementById(propertyname).value==desiredvalue)) {
                    return false
                }
                else{
                    return true
                }               
            });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("anothertest");
    </script>
}
```

Test Result
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much Qiang Fu.  I am seeing that I just did not know how to reference the data elements to make this work.  This is perfect and I truly thank you for giving me a start and sending me off on my Custom Validation journey.  Much appreciated my friend.

Comment: PS - now I can give it real meaningful names in my project and move forward.  I gave it the name AnotherTest because I was so frustrated.